# I can't seem to get jquery variables to preserve their value

Tags: jquery, variables, global-variables

I'm trying to create a global variable that begins at 0, and every second gets incremented by 1. Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    time = 0;

    setTimeout(function(){
        time += 1;
    }, 1000);

});
```

The problem is that when I output the value of time (after the time += 1 line), the value is always 1.  I want it to go 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, .. and so on.  I've seen that not putting var in front of the declaration of the variable makes it global, but that didn't preserve the value.

It would seem to me that the problem is that `time = 0` is getting reset to 0 every cycle, but i have no idea how to prevent this from happening.  I can't just neglect to give time a value because adding 1 to an empty variable is bad.

How do I do this?

Comment: setTimeout will call call it only once after 1 second, so it makes sense that it stays at 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might want `setInterval` not `setTimeout`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var time = 0;

    setInterval(function () {
        time += 1;
        console.log(time);
    }, 1000);
});
```

Note the above 'time' value is scoped to the function.  If you need to make it global:

```
var time = 0;

$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(function () {
        time += 1;
        console.log(time);
    }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You only call `setTimeout()` once, so time only gets incremented once, and not repeatedly each second.  You can do this easily with a closure which builds a timer function, with a privately scoped `time` variable, that calls itself every second to update.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var timer = (function() {
    var time = 0;
    return function() {
      console.log("> time = %d", time);
      time += 1;
      setTimeout(timer, 1000);
    };
  })();

  timer();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a working JavaScript example:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head><title></title></head>
<body>
    <input />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var el, time;
        el = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
        time = 0;
        setInterval(function(){
            time++;
            el.value = time;
        }, 1000);   
    </script>
<body>
```

Note, that I used setInterval over setTimeout. This is only because it suits your goals better.